# Confusion with Python import

Tags: python, import, package

I have a package of utility modules and classes that are imported using the following example statement:

```
from MarixFramework.switcher import SwitchClient
```

When MarixFramework is installed as a package the above statement works fine. However, I want to do some local testing of the package contents, so I want to import directly from my local folder tree that has the following structure:

```
Workspace
   MarixFramework
      MarixFramework
   eBlanketBot
      -- project source files
```

If I add `Workspace\MarixFramework` to sys.path then I get the following error:

```
>>> sys.path: ['/home/pi/hd1/Projects/Workspace/MarixFramework', '', '/home/pi/hd1/Projects/Workspace/eBlanketBot', '/usr/share/eric/modules/DebugClients/Python', '/usr/lib/python37.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.7', '/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
Exception "ImportError"
cannot import name 'SwitchClient' from 'MarixFramework.switcher' (/home/pi/hd1/Projects/Workspace/MarixFramework/MarixFramework/switcher.py)
File: /home/pi/hd1/Projects/Workspace/eBlanketBot/blanketClient.py, Line: 9
```

The import procedure has obviously found the desired source file, but fails to import from it. Why?

What I am trying to achieve is to import the MarixFramework modules directly from the folder tree. Then, when my local testing is complete I can just rebuild and install it as a package without having to change the import statement syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, my mistake. It seems that relative importing using the dot syntax is possible. I had an error in my import statement - attempting to import a class from the wrong source file. Duh!
Setting up the sys.path as in the above example does work. Phew! That simplifies package testing.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).